# Can we use "Noah" as a name for a baby?

Tags: naming

My wife and I are due to have a baby in 7 weeks and have become keen on the name Noah as it will possibly keep me happy as I have Arabic roots and my wife is English.

Is it ok to use the name Noah as a boys name? I have been told it is Hebrew and do not want that. Is it used by Muslims as a boys name?

Comment: related http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/7869/giving-an-english-name-to-a-child-in-islam

Answer (score 3):

Peace be upon you,
Noah (نوح) (A.S) is a prophet's name, so, what is the sin if you give your baby a prophet's name? I mean there is no sin to name your baby as Noah. Have you not seen many people having prophets names such as Ibrahim, Imran.

Comment: Similarly, Ismail, Dawud, Suleiman, Idris, Yusuf, etc.

Answer (score 1):

of course you can. No problem with giving prophet names.

But you cannot give https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_of_God_in_Islam these names to your baby directly.

Actually you can, it is not haram but mekruh(it is better not to give) but if you insist on these names than you can just add "abd-" to beginning of these words that making name "mortal of ...."

example: don't give "Rahman" give "Abdurrahman"
         don't give "Rahim" give "Abdurrahim"
         don't give "Salam" give "Abdussalam"

Answer (score -3):

Noah is a name of a great prophet.  In Arabic it's "NuH" - " نُوح" with emphasis on the "H"

There's an entire "chapter" in the Quran named Surah Nuh #71

Comment: how does this answer the question?